# how to combine two rows in sql having same values in different columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

need to combine rows
  current data

```
id  v1    v2    v3
    1  null  null   a
    1  null  null   b
    1  null   c    null
    1  null  null    c
```

Expected output

```
 id  v1    v2    v3
1  null  null   a
1  null  null   b
1  null   c     c
```

Comment: (1) I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  (2) Please explain the logic.

Comment: thanks but I am using bigquery

Comment: Could you please explain the logic so I can help you creating a proper query?

Answer (score -1):

I think this does what you want:

```
select id, v1, max(v2), max(v3)
from t
group by id, v1, coalesce(v2, v3);
```